# magento custom admin report filter

Tags: php, magento, adminhtml

I built a custom report pretty much following this guide http://www.summasolutions.net/blogposts/custom-reports-magento. However I also want the ability to add a filter; like the one located @ Report->Sales->Orders.

I have tried to figure out where all the necessary pieces located within core are but i must be missing something. They appear to be at Mage/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Report/Filter/Form

Any help would be awesome

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php`, and go to `salesAction`, you'll see two blocks referenced:

```
$gridBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('report_sales_sales.grid');
$filterFormBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('grid.filter.form');
```

Which you can find defined in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml`, under the section marked `<adminhtml_report_sales_sale>`. Note there are some options set here through action methods. This directs you to `sales/adminhtml_report_filter_form_order`, which you can find at `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Report/Filter/Form/Order.php`, and its parent, `../Form.php`. Have a look at the `_prepareForm()` functions, that should give you a better template to work with. Note that both of these are descendants of `Mage/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Report/Filter/Form`.